# is SQL left outer join equivalent to "not in" select query?

Tags: sql, left-join

I'm trying to evaluate logic and performance of the following 2 queries. I'm thinking they are identical, but access graph shows different path and significantly different performance. Can someone please explain if those are logically equivalent?

```
select f.folderId FOLDERS_TO_DEL from store.Folders f 
    where f.ownerUserId not in (select u.userId from store.users u);


select f.folderId FOLDERS_TO_DEL from store.Folders f LEFT JOIN 
    store.Users u ON f.ownerUserId=u.userId WHERE u.userId IS NULL;
```

Edit: I would like to add that all ID fields are not-nullable in my examples.

Answer (score 3):

No, if there are NULLs in either `Folders.ownerUserId` or `Users.userId`, they behave in quite different ways.

[A simple SQLfiddle demo with a null in `ownerUserId`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e36630/1).

Comment: @Marcin If the fields involved are non nullable, they'll give the same result (but as you're seeing not necessarily the same query plan)